# Dissertation tribute/acknowledgement

Tags: thesis, dedication

I've recently completed my dissertation and would like to know the correct way to add a few words of tribute to a late family member.
I'm aware of adding an acknowledgements section, but I am not too sure that it would be right. From a little research I have found that the acknowledgment section thanks everyone who has helped you whilst you have been researching and writing your dissertation.

I would like to know if anybody has any information or examples on this.

Comment: Search for "dedication" + thesis. Here's [one example](http://cool.conservation-us.org/byauth/roggia/barrow/fm-dedication.html) that combines a dedication with further acknowledgements.

Answer (score 5):

There are absolutely ways to do this.

First, if you feel like they genuinely helped in some way, the acknowledgements section is perfectly appropriate - this need not necessarily be serious. For example, I ended up thanking my mother-in-law for spending some time talking to me about how certain aspects of what she does work, along with Stack Overflow and the folks who make Dr. Pepper.

Many thesis documents also include a dedication, which is much more personal. For example, mine read:

> To my parents, for teaching me to ask questions, and to $WIFE for seeing this through with patience, love and understanding.

Comment: Lol at $WIFE ... Should have thought of that for mine